# In what way is this question "unclear?"

Tags: discussion

Question thread [on hold] for being "Unclear": [Guide to check thesis grammar?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130003/guide-to-check-thesis-grammar)

> I'm new to the site. I'm looking for some compherensive, easy-to-use
>   guide with examples about the english grammar. I would like to improve
>   the language of my master's thesis. Suggestions?

If one were to argue that the question is "Off topic" and I would stay out of that argument, but surely the question is easily understood.  OP is looking for reference materials to improve his grammar.

So why was this question put on hold?

Answer (score 2):

1. It is unclear what the OP means by "comprehensive".
2. It is unclear what the OP means by "easy-to-use".
3. It is unclear what the OP means by "examples".
4. It is unclear what the OP means by "the english grammar".
5. It is unclear how the OP wishes to go about improving the language of their master's thesis by using a guide with examples.
6. It is unclear what domain we are talking about. A master's thesis in literature? In maths? In genomics?
7. Your suggesting *Strunk and White* in the comments aptly demonstrates that you yourself would give bad advice if the question were open. *Strunk and White* is not a grammar guide by any stretch of imagination.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer to reflect the content of your comment in the question?  **"Get it proofread. By a human. By a knowledgeable human. No "easy-to-use guide with examples" will help you. It will likely make everything worse, in fact. Sorry, but that's how it is."**  Your comment appears to display a comprehension of the question that contradicts your answer here.

Comment: I don't see how my comment contradicts my answer here. You are welcome to expand on how it does. NB: in the mean time I have closed the question as a duplicate of ["What are some of the better English reference grammars?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/183/), and there's yet another related question linked from MetaEd's comment. However, it is still not clear if that is what the OP really wants. The concerns I listed above have not been addressed.

Comment: By all means, I am happy to expand.  At no point in your comment do you assert a lack of understanding for OP's question.  **"No 'easy-to-use guide with examples' will help you"** implies that you understand what is meant by 'easy-to-use guide with examples.'  If you didn't understand what it meant, you would be in no position to postulate on its efficacy, would you?

Comment: When I was writing that comment, I had the exact same questions going through my mind that I listed above. (Yes, including number seven. I was totally expecting someone to recommend S&W, which is precisely what prompted me to add the "it will likely make everything worse" bit.)

Comment: Thank you for changing the reason to "duplicate."  I think the newly provided reason will be more helpful to OP.

Comment: [continued] I don't have to know what OP's definition of an easy-to-use guide is in order to comment that "no easy-to-use guide with examples will help you". I can leave that comment according to *my* understanding of what constitutes such a guide. It is not clear, however, that my understanding is that of the OP's. He might have something totally different in mind. Which is why the question was put on hold pending further clarification *what* it is he has in mind. (Do note how he hasn't so much as specified his budget, or how much time he's willing to invest.)